# Lidando com datas de formatos heterogêneos no R

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

Eu possuo 236 arquivos em .csv que possuem todos as mesmas colunas. Meu objetivo é juntá-los todos em um data frame apenas.

Entretanto, cada um deles possui 4 colunas com valores de data e hora. O problema está nas colunas referentes a data e hora. Algumas datas estão no formato `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, como `2019-10-08 10:15:00`. Outras datas estão no formato `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM`, como `01/08/2001 21:56`.

Para o primeiro caso, eu usaria a função `ymd_hms` do pacote `lubridate` para criar um objeto do tipo POSIXct:

```
library(lubridate)

ymd_hms("2019-10-08 10:15:00")
[1] "2019-10-08 10:15:00 UTC"
```

Para o segundo caso, eu usaria a função `dmy_hm` do mesmo pacote para obter o resultado que desejo:

```
dmy_hm("01/08/2001 21:56")
[1] "2001-08-01 21:56:00 UTC"
```

Mas como preceder no caso em que eu possuo os dois formatos de data, ainda como caracteres, em um mesmo vetor? Em outras palavras, como converter o vetor de caracteres `x`, dado abaixo

```
x <- c("2019-10-08 10:15:00", "01/08/2001 21:56")
```

em um vetor do tipo POSIXct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar o parâmetro `tryFormats` da função `as.POSIXct` junto com alguma função tipo `apply`, aí ele testa para cada valor qual dos formatos fornecidos é o apropriado.

```r
library(magrittr)
x <- c("2019-10-08 10:15:00", "01/08/2001 21:56")
lapply(x, as.POSIXct, tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")) %>% 
  do.call(c,.)
#> [1] "2019-10-08 10:15:00 -03" "2001-08-01 21:56:00 -03"

library(tidyverse)
map(x, as.POSIXct, tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")) %>% 
     reduce(c)
#> [1] "2019-10-08 10:15:00 -03" "2001-08-01 21:56:00 -03"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Esta função resolve o problema para vetores em que todos os elementos estejam num dos dois formatos da pergunta. A função pode facilmente ser tornada mais geral, caso seja necessário.

```
as_POSIXct_especial <- function(x){
  sp <- strsplit(x, '[ -/]')
  res <- lapply(seq_along(sp), function(i){
    k <- which(nchar(sp[[i]]) == 4)
    if(k == 1){
      lubridate::ymd_hms(x[i])
    }else if(k == 3){
      lubridate::dmy_hm(x[i])
    }else{
      NA
    }
  })
  tz <- substring(res[[1]], first = nchar(x[[1]]) - 2)
  as.POSIXct(unlist(res), origin = "1970-01-01", tz = tz)
}

x <- c("2019-10-08 10:15:00", "01/08/2001 21:56")
as_POSIXct_especial(x)
#[1] "2019-10-08 10:15:00" "2001-08-01 21:56:00"
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode verificar o formato da data utilizando a função substr e transformar para o formato certo, o código abaixo resolve o problema para o vetor x:

```
x <- c("2019-10-08 10:15:00", "01/08/2001 21:56")
x <- ifelse(substr(x,3,3) == "/", dmy_hm(x), ymd_hms(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução ainda mais simples é usar a função `parse_date_time` do pacote `lubridate`.

```
library(lubridate)

y <- parse_date_time(x = x, orders = c("y m d H M S", "d m y H M"))

y

#[1] "2019-10-08 10:15:00 UTC" "2001-08-20 01:21:56 UTC"
```

O qual é objeto de classe `POSIXct`:

```
class(y)

[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Detalhes sobre o uso da função `parse_date_time` encontram-se [aqui](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/parse_date_time.html).